# Find if an angle is within X degrees from another

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, angle

I need an algorithm to figure out if one angle is within a certain amount of degrees from another angle.

My first thought was `(a-x < b) && (a+x > b)`, but it fails when it has to work with angles that wrap around from -179 to 180.

[image]

In the diagram above, the region (green) that the angle must be between wraps between the negative and positive sides. How can I determine whether the angle (the red line) falls inside this region?

Comment: Try the updated version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this formula:

```
360-(|a-b|)%360<x || (|a-b|)%360<x
```

Or, [in PHP](http://codepad.org/LOJQ8U7i):

```
<?php

$b = 10;
$angle1 = -179;
$angle2 = 180;

$diff = $angle1 - $angle2;
if(abs($diff % 360) <= $b || (360-abs($diff % 360))<=$b) {
  echo "yes";
} else {
  echo "no";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Marcel rightly points out, modulo on negative numbers is potentially problematic. Also, what is the difference between 355 and 5 degrees? It might be worked out to be 350 degrees but 10 degrees is probably what people are expecting. We make the following assumptions:

1. we want the smallest positive angle between two other angles so `0 <= diff <= 180`;
2. we are working in degrees. If radians, substitute 360 for `2*PI`;
3. angles can be positive or negative can be outside the range `-360 < x < 360` where x is an input angle and
4. order of input angles or the direction of the difference is irrelevant.

Inputs: angles a and b. So the algorithm is simply:

1. Normalize a and b to `0 <= x < 360`;
2. Compute the shortest angle between the two normal angles.

For the first step, to convert the angle to the desired range, there are two possibilities:

- `x >= 0`: normal = x % 360
- `x < 0`: normal = (-x / 360 + 1) * 360 + x

The second is designed to remove any ambiguity on the difference in interpretation of negative modulus operations. So to give a worked example for x = -400:

```
  -x / 360 + 1
= -(-400) / 360 + 1
= 400 / 360 + 1
= 1 + 1
= 2
```

then

```
normal = 2 * 360 + (-400)
       = 320
```

so for inputs 10 and -400 the normal angles are 10 and 320.

Now we calculate the shortest angle between them. As a sanity check, the sum of those two angles must be 360. In this case the possibilities are 50 and 310 (draw it and you'll see this). To work these out:

```
normal1 = min(normal(a), normal(b))
normal2 = max(normal(a), normal(b))
angle1 = normal2 - normal1
angle2 = 360 + normal1 - normal2
```

So for our example:

```
normal1 = min(320, 10) = 10
normal2 = max(320, 10) = 320
angle1 = normal2 - normal1 = 320 - 10 = 310
angle2 = 360 + normal1 - normal2 = 360 + 10 - 320 = 50
```

You'll note `normal1 + normal2 = 360` (and you can even prove this will be the case if you like).

Lastly:

```
diff = min(normal1, normal2)
```

or 50 in our case.

Comment: Have you a typo there between angle1 and angle2?

Comment: Modulo on a potentially negative number (diff) might be dangerous in some languages.

Comment: Is that relying on the angle being 0 - 360, or can I use it with angles being between -180 and 180?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a dot product:

```
cos(a)*cos(b) + sin(a)*sin(b) >= cos(x)
```

Comment: This is very elegant and removes ambiguities all at once.

Answer (score 1):

For a radius of 1, the distance between the line endpoints is 2sin((a-b/2). So throw away the 2 since you are only interested in a comparison, and compare sin(x/2) with sin((a-b)/2). The trig functions take care of all the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

c++ implementation:

```
float diff = fabsf(angle1 - angle2);
bool isInRange = fmodf(diff, 360.0f) <= ANGLE_RANGE ||
                 360.0f - fmodf(diff, 360.0f) <= ANGLE_RANGE;
```